# Sync Notes on iphone with a txt file on windows PC

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, notes.app

Is there any way to sync a txt file on the windows filesystem with a Notes file on the iOS device- iphone or ipad. I regularly take my notes on my PC but want them to be viewable on my iPhone. Could be through a cloud technology such as iCloud/dropbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

Using Dropbox, save your files on your Dropbox folder and access them on your iPhone through:

- The Dropbox app, tap on a file. I think Dropbox has a built in text editor, or you can select any text-editing app on your device to view/edit it.
- Any of the many dedicated text editing apps with built in Dropbox support, such as [Elements](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/elements/), [Droptext](http://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/droptext-text-editor-for-dropbox/id371880635?mt=8), etc. Look around a bit.

Using iCloud, create notes using the native app. They will be accessible on your PC through:

- iCloud.com. Click on mail and select the folder
  called "Notes". Note though, you wont be able to edit them just now on this site.
  Nonetheless, Apple is supposed to be releasing an update to their
  iCloud.com website during the next month or two and give it a
  dedicated notes application, which will likely allow for editing
  within the web interface.
- Outlook. Install the [iCloud Control Panel](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for windows, and check the box that allows you to syinc notes. Note though, you need a compatible version of Outlook.

Comment: i bought iA writer and tried the dropbox solution. its pretty good. however I have a lot of content in the Apple Notes app. its probably not easy to sync with Notes and PC filesystem .txt file

Comment: Indeed, I don't think there is an easy way to do this. If you want your iPhone Notes app notes on on a text file, the only thing I can think of doing is copy/pasting to a new .txt, either on your iPhone or on your computer through the mail web app. :/